# How to save HTML data in Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, html, sql-server

I have feedback panel where user can write HTML formated feedback using [AJAX HTMLEditor](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/htmleditor/htmleditor.aspx)

I want to save this HTML DATA in SQL server

**HTML SOURCE**

```
This is <span style="font-weight: bold; ">nice</span> question
```

**HTML OUTPUT**

```
This is nice question
```

Now how can i search to my database if your find "is nice" then my query can not response is nice because database contains HTML tags too.

So what are best practices to save and retrieve HTML data using SQL Query & ASP.net.

Answer (score 5):

You might get some mileage out the SQL Server's full-text search capability. Here is a resource that describes strategies to apply full-text search to HTML text stored in SQL Server:

http://www.developmentnow.com/blog/SQL+Server+2005+Full+Text+Search+On+HTML+Documents.aspx

Comment: The above given link has different options and all has Upsides/Downsides
so what is best final and best methods

Comment: @SOF: That is a fair question. I'm afraid you will have to weigh the advantages and disadvantages in your specific scenario to decide whether this implementation is reasonable. I believe it is. `LIKE` clauses are extremely limited, as your question so eloquently demonstrates. A carefully implemented full-text index may not be perfect, but it extends the boundaries beyond what is possible with simpler indexes and queries.

Comment: Updated link referenced in the answer, which I think is still relevant: http://developmentnow.com/2006/08/12/sql-server-2005-full-text-search-on-html-documents/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 then full-text indexing is a good option. Store your HTML in a varbinary(max) column and set its associated file type to ".html" in a file type column.  The full-text indexer will parse the data as HTML and search only the text content while ignoring the HTML tags.

Comment: Nice.. But GoDady gives us SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: @SOF User: Full text indexing is in SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005

Comment: Not sure if SQL Server 2005 has the HTML filter for full-text indexing, might just be a 2008 thing.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data twice in two different columns; once as HTML and another as just plain text. Do the display from the HTML column, and perform any searches against the text column.

Comment: Its interesting answer this was already my last choice :)
but i dont want to duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is to use a CTE to strip out the HTML before doing a search.

The following CTE extracts likely rows that satisfy the search criteria and recursively strips out the HTML. The Query then uses the results of the CTE to filter out rows still containing HTML and ones that don’t exactly match the search criteria.

The CTE isn’t as complicated as it looks. Most of the fiddling is to cope with PATINDEX returning 0.

```
--** Test table
DECLARE @HTML TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, html VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @HTML SELECT 'This is a <span style="font-weight: bold; ">nice</span> question';
INSERT INTO @HTML SELECT 'The cat sat <span style="font-weight: bold; ">on the</span> mat';

--** Search criteria
DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(50) = 'is a nice';

--** CTE to return the matching rows ignoring the HTML
;WITH Search_CTE (html_id, html_text)
AS (
    SELECT h.id AS 'html_id'
         , LEFT(h.html,REPLACE(PATINDEX('%<%',h.html)-1,-1,999999)) + SUBSTRING(h.html,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(PATINDEX('%>%',h.html)+1,1,999999)),LEN(h.html)) AS 'html_text'
      FROM @HTML AS h
     WHERE h.html LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@Search,' ','%') + '%'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT c.html_id AS 'html_id'
         , LEFT(c.html_text,REPLACE(PATINDEX('%<%',c.html_text)-1,-1,999999)) + SUBSTRING(c.html_text,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(PATINDEX('%>%',c.html_text)+1,1,999999)),LEN(c.html_text)) AS 'html_text'
      FROM Search_CTE AS c
     WHERE PATINDEX('%<%',c.html_text) > 0
)
SELECT h.html AS 'Original HTML'
     , cte.html_text AS 'HTML Text'
  FROM Search_CTE AS cte
  JOIN @HTML AS h
    ON h.id = cte.html_id
 WHERE PATINDEX('%<%',cte.html_text) = 0   --** Filter out rows still containing HTML
   AND html_text LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'; --** Filter out rows not matching the search criteria
```

This query has the limitation that it doesn't handle the situation where > or < is in the text, but this can be coded around if required.