# How to Preserve Formatting in a Multi-Line Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website where I create a textbox multi-line at runtime depending on some selections for example, they specify the number of lines and the width, then I create the textbox and put it in a panel on the next page. My issue is that in the textbox they would like to write something like this:

```
   Company Name
   123 Test Avenue
   New York, NY 10001
```

I would like to preserve the formatting, what i mean by this is keeping the next lines as a block, right now if they entered it like that in the textbox it would show like this:

```
Company Name 123 Test Avenue New York, NY 10001
```

Is there a way at all to do this with `<asp:TextBox/>` multi-line ?.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: fair enough, will remember next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a control like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) . ([Rich text editors for asp.net](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&tbo=d&q=free%20asp.net%20rich%20text%20editor&oq=free%20asp.net%20rich%20text%20editor&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30j0i8j0i8i30l6j0i22.5934.7477.0.7754.9.7.2.0.0.0.265.1210.1j2j4.7.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.FaZb_kFN7IQ))

TextArea (asp:textbox with mode="multiline") does not save the formatting, which in your case is `<br/>`

To persist the rich text into the database you need to think of possible problem in advance.

[How to save HTML data in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490648/how-to-save-html-data-in-sql-server)

[how to save html to a database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914464/how-to-save-html-to-a-database-field)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1669475.aspx/1