# ASP.NET Save Formatted text in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, formatting

I have the following textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txtText" runat="server" Height="135px" 
    Width="355px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
```

how can I save the formatted text (text with line spacing mostly) and display it in another div/label or save it in database?

I tried to save it database using both `nvarchar` or `text` data but text is being passed as a one liner all the time.

Comment: `data but text is being passed as a one liner all the time.` How exactly did you verify this?

Comment: check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638169/how-to-preserve-formatting-in-a-multi-line-text-box

Comment: @asawyer breakpoints and assiging the texbox text to div/label directly on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by saving the text in a string and replacing `\r\t` with `<br/>` before saving to the database:

```
string text = txtText.Text;
text = text.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
//save to database
```